# Do I need to worry about unauthorized users with registered accounts?

Tags: security, joomla-3.6

I just updated my site to 3.6.4 and in doing some maintenance noticed that there were unauthorized users added to the site to the registered users group. I was able to delete the users without a problem, some were obviously spammers, some with domain name suffixes coming from eastern Europe.

Do I need to worry about what I registered user could do with privilege escalation? should I change all the server passwords? I've read that the 3.6.4 update was specifically to fix a privilege escalation exploit, but what else should I do?

Comment: From the pattern, I believe they are just regular spammers, but changing your credentials (user/server passwords) regularly is one of the most effective way to prevent potentials security problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user escalation problem is fixed on 3.6.4, so, if you are using this version, you shouldn't have this problem.

Nevertheless, I suggest you disable user registration on your website. This is explained [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/allow-user-registration-should-be-set-to-no-by-default-on-joomla). If you do need user registration on the frontend of your website, then make sure that only an administrator is able to activate these accounts.